# Has NSTextView go some sort of line or text limit imposed by default

Tags: macos, nstextview

I am trying to load a text file with 1060 lines of text and display it in a NSTextView but only the first 50 or 60 lines or so is displaying and i cant scroll past that point.
I have NSLog(ed) the content of the textviews string property and I is can see the whole file in the log.

PS I have used UITextViews under iOS with no such problems I know they are different but i would expect similar behaviour.

regards Christian Stœr Andersen

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a problem with auto layout not an issue with NSTextView I learned a lot about the NSLayoutManager

Regards Christian Stœr Andersen

Comment: You really should share what you learn so that others can benefit, not just yourself.